# React Native Geolocation doesn't show

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

So I tried following [this tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/react-native-basics-geolocation-adf3c0d10112) to watch my users' geolocation with react-native-maps:

When I access my app on my phone, it shows the text "longitude:" and "latitude:" but no real values are seen next to them. I can get the standing geolocation upon entering the app but I cannot watch it. My code is as follows:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  View, Text
} from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';

export default class FindPotato extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      latitude: null,
      longitude: null,
      error: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        });
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000, distanceFilter: 10 },
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchId);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.watchId);
    return (
      <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</Text>
        <Text>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</Text>
        {this.state.error ? <Text>Error: {this.state.error}</Text> : null}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it with the code in the tutorial? i.e. without the `this.watchId`?

Comment: you need to check position if it has value.